# Need to move updated values in motion.c and change direction

Tags: c, arrays, direction

I need some help with an assignment that's due in a few days. I'm asked to do the following:

**motion.c:**

*This external function takes the form:
int motion (int nodeid, int row, int column, int direction)
Starting in the row and column of the field specified in the function arguments, this routine places nodeid
in that field location. Then, based on the direction integer (0-3), motion moves one spot in the appropriate
direction, increments nodeid, and deposits the updated nodeid in the next position in that direction. Motion
continues placing integers on the field until after it has placed an integer on the edge of the field.*

**main.c:**

*Your assignment is to write a C program that first reads in a single line of input which contains the integer
samples. main then reads in samples lines of test data. Each sample line of test data contains four integers
corresponding to:
nodeid row column direction
For each sample of test data your program does the following:

1) Clear the field (i.e., fill the field array with zeros).

2) Call motion using the sample test data as arguments.

3) Call print_field to print out the resultant field to stdout.*

Here's the code for motion.c I did so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "motion.h"

int motion (int nodeid, int row, int column, int direction) {

nodeid = field [row][column];

while (((row < LENGTH)&&(row >= 0))||((column < WIDTH)&&(column >= 0)))
{
if (direction == 0)
{
nodeid++;
nodeid = field [row][(unsigned int)column + 1];
column++;
}
else if (direction == 1)
{
nodeid++;
nodeid = field [row][(unsigned int)column - 1];
column--;
}
else if (direction == 2) 
{
nodeid++;
nodeid = field [(unsigned int)row - 1][column];
row--;
}
else if (direction == 3) 
{
nodeid++;
nodeid = field [(unsigned int)row + 1][column];
row++;
}
}

return 0;
}
```

And this is for main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "motion.h"

int main() {

int samples;
int i;
int j;
int k;

printf ("How many samples do you want?\n");
scanf ("%d", &samples);

for (i = 0; i < samples; i++)
{
printf ("Indicate nodeid, row, column and direction\n");
scanf ("%d %d %d %d", &nodeid, &row, &column, &direction);
for(j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
{
for(k = 0; k < WIDTH; k++)
{
field[j][k] = 0;
}
}
motion (nodeid, row, column, direction);
printf ("\n%d", print_field(field, row, column));
}

return 0;
```

And this is my header file:

```
#define WIDTH 12
#define SAMPLES 8
enum direction {Right, Left, Up, Down};
int field [LENGTH][WIDTH];
int column;
int row;
int nodeid;
int direction;
int motion (int nodeid, int row, int column, int direction);
int print_field (int field[][ WIDTH ], int row, int column);
```

In motion.c, I'm asked to move the parameter nodeid in my array, either right, left, up or down. Every time I move my nodeid, I increment my nodeid and depending on my direction, I increment or decrement my row or column. Trouble is, I don't know how to switch directions once I make a single move: by that, I mean that although I assign a direction in the motion function from main.c, I have no idea how to change it on the next round (e.g you choose to move south and then as long as the for loop conditions in motion.c are met, you can select another direction. How?) and even though I added an unsigned integer cast to my row and column to avoid going below 0, I still get segmentation violations. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
How many samples do you want?
1
Indicate nodeid, row, column and direction
1 2 1 2

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400746 in motion (nodeid=1, row=0, column=1, direction=2)
    at motion.c:21
21      nodeid = field [(unsigned int)row - 1][column];
```

I'm at a severe loss, but I wish to complete this assignment fairly (i.e. get tips and hints, not full-blown answers). Let me know ASAP where the problem lies so I can fix it!

Comment: First, you should indent your code so that it's readable. Then, are you sure that `field` is a valid array and `(unsigned int)row - 1` results in a valid index?

Comment: Can you still help me?

Comment: @H2CO3- thank you. I am getting fed up with typing that

Answer (score 0):

The runtime says exactly what happend:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400746 in motion (nodeid=1, row=0, column=1, direction=2)
    at motion.c:21
21      nodeid = field [(unsigned int)row - 1]
```

in motion function the condition in while is

```
 while (((row < LENGTH)&&(row >= 0))||((column < WIDTH)&&(column >= 0)))
```

which will be true always becuase of || condition. either left part either right part will be true,so all the condition will be true, and you will enter the loop when either row == -1 either collumn == -1.
here is working code

```
int motion(int nodeid, int row, int column, int direction)
{
nodeid = field[row][column];

while (((row < LENGTH) && (row >= 0)) &&((column < WIDTH) && (column >= 0)))
{
    nodeid++;
    if (direction == 0)
    {
        field[row][column ++] = nodeid;
    }
    else if (direction == 1)
    {
        field[row][column-- ] = nodeid;
    }
    else if (direction == 2)
    {
        field[ row --][column] = nodeid;
    }
    else if (direction == 3)
    {
        field[row++][column] =  nodeid;
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But when I first inputted row, I said 2. And I indicated that the while should terminate when it reaches 0.

Comment: no while(row>=0) means exactly as it sounds, while row bigger then zero or equals zero you will enter the loop. Try to change the condition to while (((row < LENGTH)&&(row > 0))||((column < WIDTH)&&(column > 0)))

Comment: How can I prevent row and column from going below 0? I added a condition that clearly stated that the should stay between either LENGTH or WIDTH and 0.

Comment: Tried it, still failed.

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000000000400746 in motion (nodeid=1, row=0, column=2,     direction=2)
        at motion.c:21
    21      nodeid = field [(unsigned int)row - 1][column];

Comment: Here's the thing I must indicate so that you understand:


Then, based on the direction integer (0-3), motion moves one spot in the appropriate direction, increments nodeid, and deposits the updated nodeid in the next position in that direction. Motion continues placing integers on the field until after it has placed an integer on the edge of the field.



This means that if nodeid is either at column = 0 or row = 0, then the loop stops.

Comment: This is the failure:

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000000000400746 in motion (nodeid=1, row=0, column=2,     direction=2)
        at motion.c:21
           nodeid = field [(unsigned int)row - 1][column];

Comment: It says that the loop stops once I assigned the updated value to the edge of the array. So if I'm like the bottom right, left, up and down of the array (row == 0 or column ==0) when I assign my incremented nodeid, I stop the loop.

Comment: Can you still help me? I'm in dire need of help and yet I'm doing my darnest to fix this issue!

Comment: So how do I properly assign the updated nodeid to the next array spot without overwriting it?

Comment: So nodeid =... overwrites the incremented value. I want to overwrite the initial value in the array element where I'm about to place my updated nodeid.

Comment: I don't see where you use the `nodeid` at all. You just assign it and never use it after that. Check your logic again, you know better what you want to achieve.

Comment: Dabo, can I move the updated nodeid to the next array element WITHOUT overwriting it?